# summation correct for powers of 3 but wring otherwise

Tags: c, math

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int summation(int sum,int Num[],int n) {
    if (n < 0) { 
        return sum;
    } else {    
        printf("%d \n", Num[n]);
        sum = Num[n] + summation(sum, Num, n - 1);
    }
}   

int main () {

    int i = 0, j = 0 , k = 0, n = 0;
    printf("Enter number of numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int Num[n];
    while (i < n) {
        //printf("Enter number %d : ", i);
        //scanf("%d", &Num[i]);     
        Num[i] = 1;     
        i++;        
    }
    int sum = 0;
    sum = summation(sum, Num, n);
    printf("The sum is %d \n", sum); 
}
```

The above program runs correctly only with 3
why does it generate only results for 3,3^3, 3^9??

Please help me out here this programs runs only with powers of 3. For now i have calculated 3^1,3^3 and 3^9. For other numbers it returns a wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

1. You neglect to return a value from the `summation` function. A good compiler would draw your attention to this fact.

   You call `summation` with n equal to the size of the function, which causes this line:

```
sum = Num[n] + ...
```

to read past the end of the array.

These mistakes lead to **undefined behavior,** which can show odd preferences for powers of three, or anything else.